# trying to modifying a multi join query with issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, ssms

I have a simplified query shown below, that does mulitple joins. I'm trying to add a field to be selected but I am unable to find a good way of joining it without changing the number of records that come up...

```
SELECT tblApp.AppID
,'Type' = tblRef.Label
,'Status' = tblRef2.Label
FROM (
(
    (
        tblApp LEFT JOIN tblAppExt ON tblApp.AppID = tblAppExt.AppID
        ) LEFT JOIN tblRef ON tblApp.AppTypeID = tblReferenceData.ID
    ) LEFT JOIN tblRef tblRef2 ON tblApp.AppStatusID = tblRef2.ID
)
```

As is - I'm getting 149 results, if I try to Join it in any way, I get like 10 time fold the number of records. All I'm hoping to do is be able to SELECt another field. I'm hoping to join tblAppExt2 that has AppID just like the other tables in the FROM part of the query, so my goal would basically be to do this:

```
    SELECT tblApp.AppID
    ,'Type' = tblRef.Label
    ,'Status' = tblRef2.Label
    ,'NewField' = tblAppExt2.NewField
```

Comment: Don't just post broken query, and expect someone can help you.  First of all, describe what you're trying to do.  Second, post table structure and/or relationship.  Then maybe we can help you.

Comment: Yes the answer to your question depends on your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to try is DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tblApp.AppID 
    , [Type] = tblRef.Label
    , [Status] = tblRef2.Label
    , [NewField] = tblAppExt2.NewField
FROM tblApp
    LEFT JOIN tblAppExt 
        ON tblApp.AppID = tblAppExt.AppID
    LEFT JOIN tblRef 
        ON tblApp.AppTypeID = tblReferenceData.ID
    LEFT JOIN tblRef tblRef2 
        ON tblApp.AppStatusID = tblRef2.ID
    LEFT JOIN tblAppExt2.NewField 
        ON something = somethingElse ;
```

If that doesn't work, it means there are multiple different values for [NewField] and you'll need to tell it how to select the correct one. For example, to take the most recent [NewField] you can use a CTE with the ROW_NUMBER function:

```
; WITH AllRecords
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        tblApp.AppID 
        , [Type] = tblRef.Label
        , [Status] = tblRef2.Label
        , [NewField] = tblAppExt2.NewField
        , MyRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tblApp.ID ORDER BY tblAppExt2.DateEntered DESC)
    FROM tblApp
        LEFT JOIN tblAppExt 
            ON tblApp.AppID = tblAppExt.AppID
        LEFT JOIN tblRef 
            ON tblApp.AppTypeID = tblReferenceData.ID
        LEFT JOIN tblRef tblRef2 
            ON tblApp.AppStatusID = tblRef2.ID
        LEFT JOIN tblAppExt2.NewField 
            ON something = somethingElse
        )
SELECT *
FROM AllRecords
WHERE AllRecords.MyRank = 1 ;
```

Comment: is there any way to leave the structure the way it is, just simply join on the tblAppExt2. This is an old application and i do not (neither does management) to change it, i just want to have that one additional field

Comment: Only if DISTINCT works, and that will only work if the value of NewField is the same for all joined records. Or, you can add more conditions to the LEFT JOIN ON to limit the number of matches, like "ON (tblAppExt.ClientID = tblAppExt2.ClientID) AND (tblAppExt.StateCode = tblAppExt2.StateCode)".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer apply` or correlated `subquery` :

```
SELECT tblApp.AppID, tblRef.Label as [Type], tblRef2.Label as [Status],
       tappext.NewField
FROM tblApp tapp LEFT JOIN 
     tblAppExt tex 
     ON tapp.AppID = tex.AppID LEFT JOIN
     tblRef tref 
     ON tapp.AppTypeID = tref.ID LEFT JOIN
     tblRef tblRef2
     ON tapp.AppStatusID = tblRef2.ID  OUTER APPLY
     ( SELECT TOP (1) tappext.*
       FROM tblAppExt2 tappext
       WHERE tapp.AppID = AppID 
       ORDER BY ??
     ) tappext;
```